# Do academics get paid for examining thesis?

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

Easy question, I know, and it may be obvious to some people.

I am an academic, so, let me be specific. Universities usually pay their external thesis examiners, and, I have heard that some pay their internal examiners as well.

I want to know if it's common practice to pay their internal examiners?

Thanks.

Comment: I was always paid, see page 10 of this (a bit dated): http://www.admin.ox.ac.uk/media/global/wwwadminoxacuk/localsites/educationcommittee/documents/externalexaminers/Schedule_of_Examiners_and_Supervisors_Fees_MT11.pdf

Comment: Cambridge will pay PhD examiners, internal or external, £165, plus travel expense. But other universities seem only to pay expenses. I think this varies too much to get a useful answer other than "sometimes".

Answer (score 3):

No, examiners are not always paid.

This also holds for external examiners. I have been asked to examine several theses in the last years, some internal, some external, and have never been paid. However, if the examination involves travelling, then I usually got reimbursed.

(This is an answer for Germany and Austria.)

Comment: Same here. I’m American, but I’ve been an external examiner for French, Israeli, Danish, and Dutch theses. I’ve never been paid, except for travel expenses.